# Saving a Multi-Select Checkbox Pick-list in MS CRM... PLEASE HELP

Tags: javascript, checkbox, dynamics-crm

Hey everyone, I am trying to create a Multi-Select Checkbox Pick-list within Microsoft Dynamics 4.0. I was able to create the checkbox using Jim Wangs Code from [link text](http://jianwang.blogspot.com/search/label/Picklist)
I followed the directions, I am just not sure if i need to put the values that are in my picklist within this script and if so, I have no idea where. I am kind of a newbie to Java Script so I was not sure what fields needed to be changed (or what colors mean what). Also When i insert the script and put in my PL and PLV names; I am able to see the checkbox on my Account forum screen and the values, but when i hit save and close, It will not save.  Here is a link to a picture as an example of what it looks like in the link above. In my picklist the values i have are ( Value, Value1, Value2) did this because it was a test for me to figure out where everything went and if the values needed to be in the script. As you can see in the code I have not put in the picklist values, this may be causing the save error; I just have NO idea what to change and where to insert it. I have had no luck with anyone helping me with this. So any and all help would greatly be appreciated. Please help,

Diamond

> var PL = crmForm.all.new_picklist;
>   var PLV =
>   crmForm.all.new_picklistvalue;
>   PL.style.display = "none";
>   PLV.style.display = "none";    var
>   addDiv = document.createElement("");
>   PL.parentNode.appendChild(addDiv);
>   for( var i = 1; i < PL.options.length;
>   i++ )    {      var pOption =
>   PL.options[i];      if( !IsChecked(
>   pOption.text ) )
>         var addInput = document.createElement("" );
>       var addLabel = document.createElement( "");
>
> ```
> addLabel.innerText = pOption.text;      var addBr = document.createElement(
> ```
>
> "br");
>       PL.nextSibling.appendChild(addInput); 
>   PL.nextSibling.appendChild(addLabel); 
>   PL.nextSibling.appendChild(addBr);
>   }     function IsChecked( pText )
>   {
>       if(PLV.value != "")     {
>         var PLVT = PLV.value.split("||");
>         for( var i = 1; i < PLVT.length; i++ )
>         {
>            if( PLVT[i] == pText )
>               return true;
>            }
>       }
>           return false;    }    crmForm.attachEvent( "onsave" );
>   function OnSave()    {      PLV.value
>   = "br";      var getInput = PL.nextSibling.getElementsByTagName("input");
>   for( var i = 1; i < getInput.length;
>   i++ )      {
>         if( getInput[i].checked)
>        {
>          PLV.value += getInput[i].nextSibling.innerText +
>   "||";
>        }      }

Answer (score 0):

I've seen the code you refer to. I didn't like the idea of creating two fields for something like this. I came up with the following code which works quite well. We load this little helper function through a generic js file on all our crm 4.0 pages using the following code

The following code is not directly related. Look further down for the helper function and example usage lines.

```
// Get Generic Scripts from server
try{
    var headID = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0];
    var GenericHelpers = document.createElement('script');
    GenericHelpers.type = 'text/javascript';
    GenericHelpers.src = '/ISV/GenericScripts/Generics.js';
    GenericHelpers.onload = scriptLoaded;
    GenericHelpers.onreadystatechange = function(){if (GenericHelpers.readyState == 'loaded' || GenericHelpers.readyState == 'complete'){scriptLoaded();}};
    headID.appendChild(GenericHelpers);
}
catch(err){
    alert('Failed to attach specific scripts to this form. Please contact IT Support.\n\n Specific Error: ' + err.description);
}

function scriptLoaded(){
    try{
        //all other code...
    }
    catch(err){
        alert('Form load events failed. Functionality of the form may limited or non-functional. Please contact IT Support.\n\n Specific Error: ' + err.description);
    }
}//scriptLoaded()
```

The code is quite different in it's approach. Basically we have a text field and in code we implement the various options. In the end we diverged from using this approach all together not because it didn't work but the complexity of other things we wanted to show. Instead we created a html page embedded in a iframe and the page basically pushed the information back into the text fields. Overall end goal was for an entity to drive a scheduler service.

Because the code was left in our generics.js file I assume it works but I can't say I checked it and haven't touched it since it was written. Happy to come back to it though just email me.

**Helper Function**

```
function mvHelper(oElement){

var divTag = document.createElement("<div id='list_" + oElement.id + "' style='overflow-y:auto; border:1px #6699cc solid; background-color:transparent;' />");

this.mvField = oElement;
this.mvField.style.display = "none";
this.mvField.parentNode.appendChild(divTag);

this.addTickBox = function(str){
    var addInput = null;

    if(oElement.value.indexOf(str)>=0){
        addInput = document.createElement("<input checked='true' type='checkbox' title='" + str + "' style='border:none; width:25px; align:left;' />");
    }
    else{
        addInput = document.createElement("<input type='checkbox' title='" + str + "' style='border:none; width:25px; align:left;' />");
    }

    var addLabel = document.createElement("<label style='width:65px; align:left;' />");

    addLabel.innerText = str;

    addInput.onclick = function(){
        if(this.checked){
            oElement.value += str + ',';
        }
        else{
            oElement.value = oElement.value.replace(str + ',','');
        }
    }
    divTag.appendChild(addInput);
    divTag.appendChild(addLabel);
}//mvHelper(oElement)
```

**Example Usage**

```
// crmForm.all.new_daysofweek is a text field in crm itself. 
var daysOfWeek = new mvHelper(crmForm.all.new_daysofweek);
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Mon");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Tue");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Wed");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Thu");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Fri");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Sat");
dayOfWeek.addTickBox("Sun");
```

Answer (score 0):

Just to suppliment my other post (not suggesting the above was not overly comprehensive to start with). You should be aware that the code **you have posted** stores it's information in the **text-field not the pick-list**. It's technically impossible to store it in the pick-list as the database simply can't hold multi values in the pick-list field type. The code merely uses the pick-list to get values which it translates and renders as check-boxes but drops options into the text-field.

You can also play with the html tags to create your own style here if you need/want to.

Saw some of your other posts and thought maybe this was a miss-conception on how the code works.